# Unable to connect to localhost, bs-local, etc on Browserstack

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-development-server, browserstack

I'm attempting to do some development on iOS for a model-viewer web component through browserstack (using iOS 13 Chrome) and it seems unable to connect to localhost, whether I use bs-local (as suggested via browserstack), my IP, or anything else.

I went through their troubleshooting guides with no success, and their own "Debug Connectivity" test in localhost:45454 seems to return a 200 OK response for my page, but live.browserstack.com still seems unable to connect (it returns "Unable to display the page").

I'm attempting to run it using iOS 13 on Chrome.

I've set up the proxy details, enabled 'Force Local', and installed the Browserstack Local app and have verified that it is connected correctly. The URL formats I have tried are:

```
http://localhost:8000/dev/index.html
http://bs-local.com:8000/dev/index.html
http://bs-local:8000/dev/index.html
http://<my-ip>:8000/dev/index.html
```

I am writing my code in VS Code and am using node.js/npm and `npm run serve` using Ubuntu (WSL) in the terminal to start the web dev server, which starts on its own correctly. Opening the page on my own machine seems to work fine, it is solely unable to connect through browserstack live.

Is there a step that I'm missing? What should I troubleshoot next? I'm a junior developer, so please explain in detail.